# JUnit5 - @CsvSource - converting source to POJO

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have been following some online course on JUnit testing and I came across an example of `@CsvSource`. Following example works very well.

```
@DisplayName("CSV input test")
@ParameterizedTest(name = DISPLAY_NAME_PLACEHOLDER + " - [" + INDEX_PLACEHOLDER + "] " + ARGUMENTS_PLACEHOLDER)
@CsvSource({
        "FL, 1, 1",
        "OH, 2, 2",
        "MI, 3, 3"
})
void csvInputTest(String stateCode, int val1, int val2) {
    System.out.println(stateCode + " - " + val1 + " - " + val2);
}
```

And I started wondering whether I could use some POJO instead of bazilion of arguments. So I created the POJO class with setters and getters and changed my method to:

```
void csvInputTest(StateInfo stateInfo) {
    System.out.println(stateInfo.getStateCode() + " - " + stateInfo.getVal1() + " - " + stateInfo.getVal2());
}
```

but this resulted into:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert object of type java.lang.String to type StateInfo
```

I couldn't find any fields in `@CsvSource` to specify any converter so my question is - am I able to do so? Or do I have to stick to `N-arguments` approach?

Comment: @MethodSource provides a simple way to provide Objects as parameters to a parameterized test. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The official documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-argument-aggregation-custom) explains it :

> To use a custom aggregator, implement the ArgumentsAggregator
>   interface and register it via the @AggregateWith annotation on a
>   compatible parameter in the @ParameterizedTest method. The result of
>   the aggregation will then be provided as an argument for the
>   corresponding parameter when the parameterized test is invoked. Note
>   that an implementation of ArgumentsAggregator must be declared as
>   either a top-level class or as a static nested class.

It would give :

```
public class StateInfoAggregator implements ArgumentsAggregator {
    @Override
    public StateInfo aggregateArguments(ArgumentsAccessor arguments, ParameterContext context) {
        return new StateInfo(arguments.getString(0),
                             arguments.getInteger(1),
                             arguments.getInteger(1));

    }
}

@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
        "FL, 1, 1",
        "OH, 2, 2",
        "MI, 3, 3"
})
void csvInputTest(@AggregateWith(StateInfoAggregator.class) StateInfo stateInfo) {
    System.out.println(stateInfo.getStateCode() + " - " + stateInfo.getVal1() + " - " + stateInfo.getVal2());
}
```

The documentation also adds :

> If you find yourself repeatedly declaring
>   @AggregateWith(MyTypeAggregator.class) for multiple parameterized test
>   methods across your codebase, you may wish to create a custom composed
>   annotation such as @CsvToMyType that is meta-annotated with
>   @AggregateWith(MyTypeAggregator.class).

It would give :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@AggregateWith(StateInfoAggregator.class)
public @interface CsvToStateInfo {
}

@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
        "FL, 1, 1",
        "OH, 2, 2",
        "MI, 3, 3"
})
void csvInputTest(@CsvToStateInfo  StateInfo stateInfo) {
    System.out.println(stateInfo.getStateCode() + " - " + stateInfo.getVal1() + " - " + stateInfo.getVal2());
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, tyvm!